# php type def doesn't match bind params

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 5 columns where the first column is a **primary key** and has a **Auto_INCREMENT** attribute. I am trying to insert a row into the table using the following code:

```
    <?php 

include "DBConstants.php";

$db = new DBConstants();

$connection = new mysqli($db->SERVER_NAME,$db->DB_USERNAME,$db->DB_PASSWORD,$db->DB_NAME);
$query = "INSERT INTO mailinglist (email, validationID, usRequest, isValidated) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

$statement = $connection->prepare($query);

$email = $_GET["email"];
$validationID = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes ( 10, $crstrong);
$usRequest=false;
$isValidated = false;

$statement->bind_param($email,$validationID,$usRequest,$isValidated);
$statement->execute();

$statement->close();
$connection->close();

$array = array("result"=>true,"message"=>"You have successfully subscribed");
echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

But I am getting a warning like this:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

And hence the table is not being updated. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `bind_param` should be type of corresponding bind variables.

```
$statement->bind_param('sisi', $email, $validationID, $usRequest, $isValidated);
```

*Note: Change the types in first param based on your data type.*

*[Reference Link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)*